# Class Cast exception on DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, defaulttablemodel

I have 3 Class

firs for get data from database

second for common works

other for show table.

```
public class TableContent {

private final Vector<String> headers;
private final Vector<Vector<String>> content;

public TableContent(final Vector<String> headers, final Vector<Vector<String>> content) {
    this.headers = headers;
    this.content = content;
}

public Vector<String> headers() {
    return headers;
}

public Vector<Vector<String>> content() {
    return content;
}
}
```

And:

```
public class TableData {

public TableContent getData() {
    Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<Vector<String>> content = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("Select * from table");

        headers = buildHeaders(rs);
        content = buildContent(rs);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new TableContent(headers, content);
}

private Vector<String> buildHeaders(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();

    int col = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
        headers.add(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
    }
    return headers;
}

private Vector<Vector<String>> buildContent(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Vector<Vector<String>> content = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        int col = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        Vector<String> newRow = new Vector<String>(col);

        for (int i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
            newRow.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        content.add(newRow);
    }
    return content;
}
}
```

And:

```
public class TableGUI extends JFrame {

JTable table;
TableContent data = new TableData().getData();

public TableGUI() {
    table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data.headers(), data.content()));

    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 550);
    setLocation(300, 80);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TableGUI();
}
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.justifyRows(DefaultTableModel.java:268)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(DefaultTableModel.java:224)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.<init>(DefaultTableModel.java:159)
at TableGUI.<init>(TableGUI.java:11)
at TableGUI.main(TableGUI.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is that you're passing the arguments in the wrong order. The first parameter of [`DefaultTableModel(Vector, Vector)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) is meant to be the *data*. It's the *second* parameter which is meant to be the column names. So try this:

```
table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data.content(), data.headers()));
```

Comment: So nice, it works! One another question:  I want to add my optional methods (like add, remove, edit) to my model. before i added them to my extended from `DefaultTableModel` Class, Now how can i define this methods and where should do it?

Comment: @APoliteBoy: I don't know the best way to do it offhand, not having done much Swing work. I suggest you ask a separate question for that (after checking that it's not been asked before, of course).

Answer (score 2):

I thing you are passing the wrong arguments to the constructor. According to [the constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) you have to pass the content as first and the header data as second parameter.

So you should try flipping the parameters of `DefaultTableModel` in your code:

```
table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data.content(), data.headers()));
```